# Remove one empty page between subsection and subsubsection

Tags: sectioning

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[font={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\linespread{1}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% packages for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
% packages for tables
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\usepackage{tikz}

%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}


%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{natbib}

%\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

%\usepackage[numbers,super]{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{numbers,super}



\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]



%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{\ensuremath{#1^\circ}}

\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{\footnotesize{#1}}}

\newcommand\myfootnote[1]{\footnote{\small{#1}}}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}


\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\usepackage{calc,ragged2e}
\hyphenation{gauss-ian}

\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}




\journal{Compoddddddddddddddddddddddddddddtes}


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}


\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{frontmatter}
        

        
        \title{xvcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccczvvvvvvvvvvvvv}
        
        %\tnotetext[mytitlenote]{Fully documented templates are available in the elsarticle package on %\href{http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle}{CTAN}.}
        

        
        %% or include affiliations in footnotes:
        
        
        \author[mymainaddress]{Fasdgggggggggemi}
        \author[mysecondaryaddress]{Tosdgssdgn sdgfard}
        \author[mythirdaddress]{Dosdggsdgol Yoo\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
        \cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}   \ead{dysdggggggggggggggggggggggkr}      
        
        %\ead[url]{http://fens.sabanciuniv.edu/en/people/faculty/detail/2689}
        %\href{http://fens.sabanciuniv.edu/en/people/faculty/detail/2689}{E}
        
        \address[mymainaddress]{Faasfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffdansk, Poland}
        \address[mysecondaryaddress]{Insasffffffffffff Machinery, Pafsaafolfish Academy of Sasffffffffffffffffffffffffff Pafsnd}
        \address[mythirdaddress]{Departasff Architeasffse and Architecasfasfasfafeering, Yoasfaf Universasfsafasfl, South Korea}
        
        \begin{abstract}
            
            
        \noindent Predicting the mechanical properties of reinforced concretes accurately has been a concern as these attributes are generally required by design criteria. Thus, in recent years, there has been a dramatic increase in the application of machine learning algorithms to solve complicated engineering problems. Predictive models are strong solution for time consuming numerical simulations and expensive experimental works. The present study discussed the important properties of different types of reinforced concretes as well as an extensive analysis of artificial intelligence methods utilized for predicting those attributes. Key observations, challenges, and future trends are also detailed. This work is a precious resource for researchers in choosing accurate models, which match their applications. It motivates material engineers to become familiar and employ machine learning techniques applied in this field for predicting material properties of reinforced concrete structures.
            
            
        \end{abstract}
        
        
        \begin{keyword}
    Machine learning; Data-asffffffffffffion techniques; Artificial neural network; Reinforced concrete; Mafsssssssssssssssssss


            
        \end{keyword}
        
    \end{frontmatter}
    
    
 beam, slab, column, wall, pier
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your output? I get an error for `\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}`, but no empty page

Comment: Can you please try it now. I get third page as empty in overleaf. page 2 and page 4 is full

Comment: I get 3 pages, no empty page. https://www.overleaf.com/read/kkysycthfmms

Comment: please try it now! I changed the code to the main one! Thank you. I added the photo. Third page is empty. it jumped from second to fourth

Comment: You should really, really, really clean up your preamble. You load a lot of package multiple times. The blank page seems to disappear if one removes the 3(!) times you load the `hyperref` package.

Comment: It also works if one removes the `sectsty` package.

Comment: Yes in that case. But it jumps from second to third page. if you run you will see.

Comment: I mean if you run above code without sectsty package then you will see half of page 2 is empty and it starts from page 3!

Comment: The problem is due to the consecutive `\section` or `\subsection` commands with no text in between. Since LaTeX will ***never*** break a page just after a section heading, you get an almost empty page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a false problem.

LaTeX will never break a page just after a section header and you have

```
\subsection{FRP laminate}
It has three main types of GFRP, CFRP, and AFRP.

\subsubsection{Near Surface Mounted (NSM) FRP reinforcing rebar}

\subsection{FRP reinforcing rebar}

\section{Experimental controlling test}

\subsection{Non-Destructive Testing (NDT)}

\subsection{Pull off test}

\subsection{Tensile strength test}

\section{Experimental study}

\subsection{Reinforced concrete structure}

\subsection{Steel structure}

\subsection{Infrastructure}

\section{Numerical investigation}

\subsection{Reinforced concrete structure}

\subsection{Steel structure}

\subsection{Infrastructure}

\section{Designing methods of FRP}

\section{Optimization methods}

\section{Machine learning algorithms}

\section{Recommendations and gaps}

\section{Conclusions}

\noindent In order ...
```

The only feasible page break points are after “It has three main…” and “`\noindent` In order…”

so LaTeX takes them. Add text and you'll see that the problem goes away.

---

Some comments are in order.

- If you use `elsarticle` you should *not* try and modify their page setup, caption formats and, generically, styles; so you should remove

  `geometry`, `caption`, `fullpage`, `setspace`, `fancyhdr`, `sectsty`

  You may not like `elsarticle` style, but they do. And it's the journal you submit your paper to that has the final word.
- The package `epsfig` has been obsolete for about 30 years.
- The package `latexsym` should be replaced by `amssymb`.

Loading packages several times denotes coding sloppiness. Only load the packages you need and just *once*.